# How to write loop across Hierarchical Data (household-individual) in stata?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I'm now working on a household survey data set and I'd like to give certain members extra IDs according to their relationship to the household head. More specifically, I need to identify the adult children of household head and his/her spouse, if married, and assign them "sub-household IDs".

The variables are: `hhid` - household ID; `pid` -individual ID; `relhead` - relationship with head.

Regarding `relhead`, a `1` represents the head, a `6` represents a child, and a `7` represents a child-in-law. Below some example data, including in the last column the desired outcome. I assume that whenever a `6` is followed by a `7`, they constitute a couple and belong to the same sub-household.

```
         hhid   pid  relhead         sub_hhid(desired)
          50     1    1                  1
          50     2    3                  1
          50     3    6                  2
          50     4    6                  3
          50     5    7                  3
        -----------------------------------------------
          67     1    1                  1
          67     3    6                  2
          67     4    7                  2
```

Here are some thoughts:

There may be married and unmarried adult children within one household, the family structure is a little bit complicated, so I want to write some loop across the members in a household.

The basic idea is in the outer loop we identify the children staying-at-home and then check if there's a spouse presented, if there is, then we give the couple an indicator, if not, we continue and give the single stay_chil other indicator. After walking through all the possible members within a household, we get a series of within-household IDs. To facilitate further analysis , I need some kind of external ID variable to separate the sub-families.

```
* Define N as the total number of household, n as number of individual household size
* sty_chil is indicator for adult child who living with parents(head) 
* sty_chil_sp is adult child's spouse
* "hid" and "ind_id" are local macros
forvalue hid=1/N {
  forvalue ind_id= 1/n {
       if sty_chil[`ind_id']==1 {
          check if sty_chil_sp[`ind_id+1']==1 {
          if yes then assign sub_hhid to this couples *a 6-7 pairs,identifid as couple
                                  } 
                      else                    { * single 6 identifid as single child
           assign sub_hhid to this child
                               }
          else         {         *Other relationships rather than 6, move forward
               ++ind_id           the members within a household
                       }
                   ++hid         *move forward across  households
                    }
```

The built-in stata `by,sort:` is pretty powerful but here I want to treat part of family members who fall into certain criterion and leave other untouched, so a if-else type loop is more natural for me (even `by:` may achieve my goal,it's always too tactful when situation become not so simple，and we cannot exhaust all the possible pattern of household pattern).

An immediate problem is that I don't know how to write loop across house IDs and individual IDs, because I used to acquire the household size (increment of outer loop) using `by` command (I'm not sure in this case it's 1 or the numerber of family members), and **I'm not sure if mix up the by and if loops is a good programming practice, I favor write a "full loop" in this case.** **Please give me some clues how to achieve my goal and provide (illustrate)pseudo code for me.**

An extra question is I cannot find the ado file which contains the content of `by` command, does it exist?

Comment: How do you know that in HH 50, the couple is not 3 and 5?

Comment: How is this question fundamentally different than your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857065/identify-adult-children-couples-within-households%5D%5B1%5D ? Why not _edit_ instead of posting a new one?

Comment: Whatever your programming background, you will find that avoiding explicit loops in Stata is probably the best way to go in many (but not all) cases. This I consider a "feature" of Stata, and you should take advantage of it. Stata commands already loop through all observations so trying to do it again is, likely, not right.

Comment: If you type in `which by`, you will see it is a _built-in_ construct. There is no .ado file you can inspect. Learning how to use it, is one of the most important steps in learning Stata. See http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004 for a nice introduction.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thank you for reply. There is an underlying assumption that we only identify the 6-7 pairs as a couple. Actually,after staring the data more carefully, the overwhelming majority of family pattern is 1-···-6-7-6-···-6 which means the respondent always mention his married child and his couple in the first place

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I repost this question instead of editing the previous one because I guess I made that one more like of a methodological issue rather than a technical issue.The question need to be more specific. You are right, I'm trying to rely on the stata built-in command to tackle my problem, but in this specific problem,I find it's not the most natural and flexible way. Apologize for any inappropriateness.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your post. You can always revert to the previous version, but I think it is easier to read now. I also recommend you delete the previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857065/identify-adult-children-couples-within-households%5D%5B1%5D, which I consider a draft of this new one.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I have deleted the previous post

Answer (score 2):

I will abstract from the issue of whether the assumption used to create matches is a sensible one or not. Rather, let this be an example of reaching the desired results **without** using explicit loops. Some logic and the use of *subscripting* (see `help subscripting`) can get you far.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
hhid   pid  relhead  sub_hhid
50     1    1          1
50     3    6          2
50     4    6          3
50     5    7          3
67     1    1          1
67     3    6          2
67     4    7          2
67     5    6          3
end

list, sepby(hhid)

*----- what you want -----

bysort hhid (pid): gen hhid2 = sum( !(relhead == 7 & relhead[_n-1] == 6) )

list, sepby(hhid)
```

As you can see, one line of code gets you there. The reasoning is the following:

1. `sum()` gives the running sum. The arguments to `sum()`, being conditions, can either be True or False. The `!` denotes the logical **not** (see `help operators`).
2. If it is **not** the case that the relationship is daughter/son-in-law AND the previous relationship is daughter/son, the condition evaluates to True and takes on the value of 1, increasing the running sum by 1. If it evaluates to False, meaning that the relationship is daughter/son-in-law AND the previous relationship is daughter/son, then it takes on the value of 0 and the running sum will not increase. This gives the result you seek.
3. You do this using the `by:` prefix, since you want to check each original household independently, so to speak.
4. For the the first observation of each original household, the condition always evaluates to True. This is because there exist no "previous" observation (relationship), and Stata considers `relhead` to be missing (., a very large number) and therefore, not equal to 6. This takes the running sum from 0 to 1 for the first observation of each sub-group, and so on.

Bottom line: learn how to use `by:` and take advantage of the features offered by Stata. Do not swim against the current; not here.

### Edit

Please note that instead of progressively changing your example data set, you should provide a *representative* example from the beginning. Not doing so can render answers that are initially OK, completely inadequate.

For your modified example, add:

```
replace hhid2 = 1 if !inlist(relhead,6,7)
```

That will simply assign anyone not 6 or 7 to the same household as the head. The head is assumed to always have `hhid2 == 1`. If the head can have `hhid2 != 1`, then

```
bysort hhid (relhead): replace hhid2 = hhid2[1] if !inlist(relhead,6,7)
```

should work.

You can follow with:

```
bysort hhid (pid): replace hhid2 = hhid2[_n-1] + 1 if hhid2 != hhid2[_n-1] & _n > 1
```

but because they are IDs, it's not really necessary.

Finally, use:

```
gen hhid3 = string(hhid) + "_" + string(hhid2)
```

to create IDs with the form `50_1`, `50_2`, `50_3`, etc.

Like I said before, if your data presents more complications, you should present a relevant example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,Roberto. One more problem, if there are other family members (like `3`-head's parents) in the household,and I want to assign head's `hhid2` value to him, like I adjust in my example (family 50, pid 2). In this case, your condition `(relhead == 7 & relhead[_n-1] == 6)` gonna to be false and `hhid2` for head's father becomes 2, that's not what I want. More generally,if I want to generate new household level ID variable like the original hhid,say `50_1/50_2/50_3`,what shall I do?